# Replacing paragraph tag contents with a random word from javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When a user enters the page I would like a div to be in the center with a heading, a quote underneath that is randomly picked from a list and a button to enter the site. This is all well and good but I cannot seem to get the button to fade in the main site and fade out the landing div. Here is a jsfiddle to try and help explain things more.

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/6cGHF/)

As you will probably be able to tell, I'm not that great with JavaScript or jquery and what I have done so far is from learning bits and pieces and surfing the web through code examples

I do not see why it will not work as I had a play around in jsfiddle with a simplified version of what I want to do and it worked.

[**Simplified Version**](http://jsfiddle.net/7dnUp/)

Below code is simplified version (It wouldn't let me post without adding code?)

HTML

```
<div class="landingDiv">
    <h1>LANDING DIV</h1>
    <button id="showMain">Enter Site</button>
</div>

<div class="main">
    <h1>Main Site</h1>
</div>
```

JQUERY

```
$("#showMain").click(function () {
    $(".main").fadeIn(1000);
    $(".landingDiv").fadeOut(1000);
});
```

CSS

```
.main {
display: none;
opactiy: 0;
}
```

Thanks in advanced.

Steve.

Comment: You need to include the jQuery library in your newer fiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first jQuery example threw an error:

```
$ is not defined
```

meaning jQuery is not defined/included. Which it wasn't. But in the second jsFiddle, you included jQuery.

You'll notice that on the left hand side of jsfiddle, you'll see that under the "Framewords & Extensions" heading that you can include a Framewordk - so, include jQuery!

Here is the updated fiddle with jQuery included: http://jsfiddle.net/6cGHF/1/

As you move forward in your JavaScript development, it is always a good idea to check your browsers developer tools for errors when something unexpected is happening. It always helps you, and when you ask questions on StackOverflow, providing these errors help us! :)

The shortcut for developer tools in Chrome is F12 - you can see a little red circle with an X in it if you have errors - click it for more info. But developer tools are also available in other major browsers (except IE8 and below).

---

**Edit:**

Wrap your `click()` event function in a `$(document).ready()`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#showMain").click(function () {
        $(".main").fadeIn(1000);
        $(".landingDiv").fadeOut(1000);
    });
});
```

What was happening was that your HTML file is read from top to bottom. So it would have reached your `click` function before the `#showMain` element had been read. So, jQuery couldn't find it.

The reason this wasn't a problem in jsFiddle was because all the JavaScript code was wrapped in an "onLoad" function (which is, admittedly, a little different to `$(document).ready()`) but it solved this problem for you by executing your JavaScript after everything had already been loaded. You can see that on the left hand side in the fiddle I linked above, you'll find a dropdown with "onLoad" selected. In it, you can also choose "OnDomready" (which would be equivalent to `$(document).ready()`)

**In summary:**

- **DON'T** use `$(document).ready()` in jsFiddle. You don't need it.
- **DO** use `$(document).ready()` around javascript that relies on the fact that the DOM is ready (ie. "all of your content is visible to your JavaScript").

Comment: Woops forgot that, thanks. The only problem is, I'm using jsfiddle just to show you guys, I'm building the site in Dreamweaver CS6 with jquery linked. `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` <--- like so, and nothing happens.

Comment: @user2142866 ok, please take the advice I wrote towards the end of my answer and debug the issue. Open up developer tools in your browser and check for JavaScript errors. When you find it, post it here and we can help. (also, if you can edit that bit of in your comment code and wrap it in ` characters (to make it show up as code) that would help a bit too - Stack overflow cut it up due to it having a link, so I can't see if what you wrote was valid HTML or not)

Comment: Ok, I added the characters for you and iv just checked with chromes inspect element, and the only error it was throwing was about a viewport meta tag: Viewport argument value "device-width;" for key "width" is invalid, and has been ignored. Note that ';' is not a separator in viewport values. The list should be comma-separated.

Comment: no other errors, i click the button and the the page just stays static, no changes at all.

Comment: @user2142866 So AFTER you click the "Enter Site" button, no other error pops up? Edited my answer with another suggestion... please check it out!

Comment: Ok I added the code you added to your answer. i got:Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null index.html:45
(anonymous function) I just made another jsfiddle but added some more css that i neglected as not relevant but now i think it might be. when the page first loads the landing div fades in with css

like this http://jsfiddle.net/W3FSS/ will this help?

Comment: @user2142866 put any code that is dependent on your HTML code being there inside the `$(document).ready()`. You're running into the same problem! `quote = document.getElementById("quote");` can't find the quote element because the DOM isn't ready. also, DON'T use `$(document).ready()` in jsFiddle. As I already mentioned in my answer, jsFiddle JavaScript code is already being wrapped in an onLoad event.

Comment: @user2142866 I've added a little more clarification to the answer.

Comment: Ok I have done that, (updated jsfiddle to show) and also done it in dreamweaver as well, it is now working in dreamweaver and chrome (although the fade is very glitchy) but not in the jsfiddle. I'm confused as hell. http://jsfiddle.net/W3FSS/1/ <-- never mind. just read your updated answer but it still doesn't work in jsfiddle?

Comment: @user2142866 I'm really sorry, my friend. But I will have to stop helping at some point. I have answered and re-answered the same questions already. The new jsFiddle doesn't include jQuery (you havent checked your developer tools). It also still uses `$(document).ready()` even after I have mentioned that you shouldn't use it in jsFiddle 3 times. All your answers are somewhere here. The glitchy loading can be fixed by adding `position:absolute;` to your `.landingDiv` style. Good luck. (I will say though, I DID answer your question. If you feel it appropriate, please upvote and mark as answer.)

Comment: I actually just added position absolute to it a moment before i refreshed this page, this is good enough for me :) thanks so much for your time, and probably annoying the hell out of you. im going to mark this as the answer, thanks.

Comment: @user2142866 I mean it, my apologies, but I answer these questions between tasks at work. Thank you for taking your time to use this site and I can see that you continue to persevere with your learning. I really enjoy seeing that. All the best! and thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your fiddle is you have not added jQuery so when you try and reference it with '$', a javascript error is thrown.  Simply add in the reference to a jQuery library and your fiddle works to fade out the button when clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Your problems:

1) Add jQuery library to your fiddle.

2) Remove `opacity:0;` from .main in your CSS.  The `display:none;` is sufficient.

3) Use this to fade out/in the elements:

```
$("#showMain").click(function () {
    $(".landingDiv").fadeOut(1000, function () {
        $(".main").fadeIn(1000);
    })
});
```

Comment: thanks for your input :) just tried this suggestion to the letter and still nothing. i load the page, click enter site and nothing, it just sits there.